# Approach with Magical Bridges

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I'm trying to solve http://www.spoj.com/problems/AMR11F/ .

> Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry has a circular lane having
>   N towers numbered 1 to N. Towers i and i+1 are adjacent to each other
>   for 1 ≤ i < N and also towers 1 and N are adjacent to each other. Each
>   of these towers has exactly F number of floors, numbered
>   1,2,3,..,F-1,F from bottom to top. Floors i and i+1 in a tower are
>   adjacent to each other and it takes one second to move between them.
>   It also takes one second to move between floor 1 of a tower and floor
>   1 of its adjacent tower. Apart from these, there are M bridges
>   designed for a quick escape in case of a Death Eater attack, each of
>   which connects two floors of different towers. Each of these bridges
>   is given as bi fi bj fj t, meaning it takes t seconds to move along
>   this bridge that connects the floor fi of tower bi and the floor fj of
>   tower bj. All ways are bidirectional.
>
> Given (qbi,qfi) and (qbj,qfj), find the minimum time in seconds it
>   takes to reach floor qfj of tower qbj, starting from floor qfi of
>   tower qbi. You have to answer a lot of such queries.
>
> Input (STDIN):
>
> The first line contains the number of test cases T. T cases follow.
>   Each test case consists of N F M in the first line. N is the number of
>   towers, F is the number of floors in each tower and M is the number of
>   bridges. M lines follow, each of the form bi fi bj fj t, as mentioned
>   in the problem statement. Next line contains Q, the number of queries
>   and Q lines follow, each of the form qbi qfi qbj qfj.
>
> Output (STDOUT):
>
> For each query of the form qbi qfi qbj qfj, output one line denoting
>   the minimum time in seconds it takes to reach the floor qfj of tower
>   qbj, starting from the floor qfi of tower qbi.
>
> Constraints:
>
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 3
>
> 2 ≤ N, M ≤ 100
>
> 2 ≤ F ≤ 1,000,000
>
> 1 ≤ t ≤ 1,000,000
>
> 1 ≤ Q ≤ 100,000
>
> 1 ≤ bi, bj, qbi, qbj ≤ N
>
> 1 ≤ fi, fj, qfi, qfj ≤ F

My first approach was to use dikjstra and represent every floor as a node. But the problem with that is number of floors comes out to be 10^8 and that'll go out of memory for sure.

I then read somewhere that I should represent only those floor as nodes in the graph which are actually connected using the bridges. But in this case the problem was in the query part as the queried floor may not be present in the graph.

Can anyone please shed some light on this matter ?

Thanks,
Umair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not represent each floor as a node. Notice that the number of bridges is limited to 100.

Hence your graph should consist of only those floors that are connected through bridges (or they are the lowest floors through which you can jump to neighbouring towers).

Since you will be asked multiple queries for shortest paths, running Dijksra's for each query would be inefficient, so I would suggest "All Pairs shortest paths" algorithms such as the Floyd Warshall's or Johnson's algorithms.

You can run any of the APSP algorithms once and build a 2-D array of shortest paths between any two pair of nodes. Thus you will get O(1) response time.

Also, notice that the query floors may not be present in your graph. I leave that to you to take care of this.

Comment: It's been a day that I'm think of a way to tackle the query part i.e. the given node not present in the graph. I thought of finding the path from the nearest node but that's not gonna solve the problem.

Comment: @omerjerk If the query floors are not in the nodes list, accomodating this is trivial because the shortest path between those new floors shall include the shortest path between two nodes already calculated. You will have to move to another tower through a bridge or the 1st floor. So simply find the nearest possibilities for both the end points and check which one gives you the shortest distance.

Comment: What do you mean by "which one gives you the shortest distance" ?

Comment: @omerjerk From any floor not in the nodes list, you can either go up or down. So check which node is reached if you go up and which one is reached if you go down. These are the only two possibilities. Doing this for both end points makes 4 possibilities.

Comment: @omerjerk Try to make small test cases and check the ones for which your program gives wrong answers.